# Git subtree update on bare repository

Tags: git

I am trying to mirror repo B as a subtree into repo A. It would be great to update it via a cron job. Therefore I am trying to do this on a server, where I host bare repositories.

Details:
I have the bare repositories repo/A and repo/B, created as bare repositories. Now I want to use B as a subtree of A; something like this: repo_A/sub_B -> repo/B/master

As repo_A/sub_B should be read only I want to update sub_B on a regulary basis via a cron job.
I just can't figure out how to do this on a bare repository without cloning it to a temp folder.

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at `git help submodule` or http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules?

Submodules solve the repo-in-another-repo problem; you will just have to tackle the task of creating the cron job to regularly commit (in repo/A) any upstream changes in repo/B. Note however that consumers of repo/A (i.e. people that have cloned it) will still need to run `git submodule update` to get new changes to repo/B, even when updating repo/A.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'd better want to go with subtrees instead of submodules. I want to have the ability to branch and modify my subtrees in repo_B without altering upstream